# C++ date Type class .. after compilation some function work well but the other not

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

in below there is the Header File for dateType.

h class. after debug it showing in consul windows this :
[Consul Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v1td.png)

Header File : dateType.h

```
#ifndef dateType_H
#define dateType_H

class dateType
{
public:
    void setDate(int, int, int);
    void setMonth(int);
    void setDay(int);
    void setYear(int);

    void print() const;

    int numberOfDaysPassed();   

    int numberOfDaysLeft();

    void incrementDate(int nDays);

    int getMonth();
    int getDay();
    int getYear();

    int getDaysInMonth();

    bool isLeapYear();

    dateType(int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900);

private:
    int dMonth;
    int dDay;
    int dYear;
};

#endif
```

main() Function :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include "dateType.h"

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout <<" Program work with data type"<<endl;

    dateType myDate(1,1,1900);

    cout << "\n\n The current Date is : "<<endl;
    myDate.print();
    cout <<endl;

    cout <<"\n\n days in this year are :" <<endl;
    myDate.getDaysInMonth();
    cout <<endl;

    cout <<"\n\n Days passed in this year are :"<<endl;
    myDate.numberOfDaysPassed();
    cout <<endl;

    cout <<"\n\n Days remaining in this year are :"<<endl;
    myDate.numberOfDaysLeft();
    cout <<endl;



    myDate.incrementDate(7);
    cout <<"\n\n New date after adding days is "<<endl;
    cout <<endl;

    myDate.print();
    cout <<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Implementation file .cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dateType.h"

using namespace std;

void dateType::setDate(int month,int day,int year)
{
    setYear(year);
    setMonth(month);
    setDay(day);
}

void dateType::setMonth(int month)
{
    if(month > 0 && month < 13)
        dMonth =month;
    else
        dMonth = 1;
}

void dateType::setDay(int day)
{
    int days[12]= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if (isLeapYear())
        days[1]++;
    if(day >= 1 && day <=days [dMonth -1])
        dDay =day;
    else
        dDay =1;
}

void dateType::setYear(int year)
{

    if (((int)log10((double)year) + 1)!=4)
        dYear = 1990;
        else dYear = year;
}


int dateType::getDaysInMonth()
{
    int days[12]= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        if (isLeapYear())
        days[1]++;
        return days[ dYear -1 ];
}
int dateType::numberOfDaysPassed()
{
    int days[12]= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int m, daysPassed;
        if (isLeapYear())
        days[1]++;
        m = dYear-1;
        daysPassed=0;
        while(m>0)
        {
            daysPassed+= days[m-1];
            m--;
        }
        daysPassed+= dDay;
        return daysPassed;
}
int dateType::numberOfDaysLeft()
{
    int daysRemaining=365;
    if (isLeapYear())
        daysRemaining++;
    daysRemaining-= numberOfDaysPassed();
    return daysRemaining;
}

void dateType::incrementDate(int nDays) 
{
    while ((nDays + dDay) > dateType::getDaysInMonth())
    {
        nDays -= dateType::getDaysInMonth();
        if (dMonth == 12)
        {
            dMonth = 0;
            dYear++;
        }   
        dMonth++;
    }
    dDay += nDays;
}


int dateType::getDay()
{
    return dDay;
}

int dateType::getMonth()
{
    return dMonth;
}
int dateType::getYear()
{
    return dYear;
}


void dateType::print() const
{
    cout <<"\n\t"<<dMonth<<"-"<<dDay<<"-"<<dYear;
}
dateType::dateType(int month, int day, int year)
{
    setDate(month,day,year);
}

bool dateType::isLeapYear()
{
    if (dYear % 400 == 0 || ( dYear % 100 !=0 && dYear % 4 ==0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I am not sure about calculating I thing i did wrong with these :
days in this year are :
Days passed in this year are :
Days remaining in this year are :

Answer (score 0):

The functions `getDaysInMonth`, `numberOfDaysPassed` and `numberOfDaysLeft` don't print anything, they only return a value.

You have to print the value, so something like `std::cout << myDate.getDaysInMonth() << '\n';`

---

You print `days in this year are :`, but the function you call is `getDaysInMonth`. I don't know which one you need, but the logic is for both wrong.

- If you need the days in the year, then you only need to return `365` or `366`, depending if it is a leap year or not.
- If you need the days in the month, you should decrement `dMonth` instead of `dYear`, as you want the month, and not the year (because you are currently use the year as index, you're accessing memory you don't own, which will result in an access violation exception or some random value).

The function `numberOfDaysPassed` calculates `m` as follows `m = dYear - 1;`, but again, you should be using `dMonth`. You should also consider using a `for` loop instead of a `while`:

```
for (int i = dMonth - 1; i > 0; --i)
    daysPassed += days[i - 1];
```